# Highlight Background No Transparency in Opera

Tags: css, background, opera, opacity, highlight

I have some CSS that changes the background color when you highlight any text on the page:

```
*::selection {
    background:#083875;
    color:white;
}
*::-moz-selection {
    background:#083875;
    color:white;
}
```

The problem is that the background color of this text (on highlight) is slightly transparent. Is there any way to make the background completely solid using only css?

This issue is occurring in Opera 25.

Comment: What browser?  Testing in the latest build of Firefox and the highlight background is a solid, non-transparent color.

Comment: Here is a test example: http://jsfiddle.net/j9u9qx8x/  Highlight the text and you'll see no difference in the shade of blue between the yellow and green background.

Comment: I'm on Opera 25. Even in your fiddle, I'm still getting the transparency.

Comment: You should be specifying the browser in your question, especially if it's an issue specific to Opera.  Have you tested in other browsers to see if it's specific to Opera?  Typical first steps to take in debugging.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. I am still in the early stages of learning css, so I completely forgot about cross-browser differences. It sounds like it's an Opera specific thing, so it really isn't a big deal (not many users highlight anything anyway). I guess I'll just leave it as it is.

Comment: No worries ;)  Opera has a small market-share anyways and the issue you are having is miniscule (won't affect user interaction).  I wouldn't fret over it too much, although I do agree that Opera should interpret a background color as a solid, non-transparent color if explicitly defined as such.

Answer (score 1):

In Opera 25, you can't control the opacity of the selection of text.

Even forcing the opacity using the `rgba(0,0,0,1)` produces a semi-transparent background.

```
*::selection {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,1);
    color:white;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j9u9qx8x/1/

**Test results in Opera 25**
[image: Results In Opera]

Perhaps try submitting a support ticket to the Opera development team to see if they can allow this functionality.  It makes sense that you should be able to override the transparent effect by forcing the opacity in the `rgba()` color syntax.